# I lost my phone and changed my Google password. Is there any way to wipe the data on my phone now?

Tags: lost-phone, remote-wipe

I lost my LG P500 a few hours ago and the first thing that came to my mind was to change my Google account password. Now I cannot install AndroidLost or another such application remotely and I really need to wipe the phone clear because there is sensitive data on it. I know I should have thought about this before changing my password. Since Google doesn't allow you to keep an old password again, I am in a huge fix. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: One option is to contact your carrier. AT&T has claimed to be able to remotely wipe a lost/stolen device. It doesn't hurt to ask.

Comment: I'm from India. We don't have service provider locked phones here plus the phone has switched off by whoever has it. But I'll get in touch with my provider to see if they can do anything. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I wish I could be of more help.